# using python, get a list of directories for parallel script execution

Tags: python, directory

I need to be able to get a list of directories with the following pattern:

/app/{APP_NAME}/current/bin

in order to run start and stop scripts.  The problem I run into is that, depending on the node, there could be between one and 22 such directories on any given node, and I need a "generic" means to get all these directories into a list and run the stop or start scripts within them in parallel.

Comment: maybe you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a globbing problem.

First let's make bunch of dirs in the same-ish hierarchy as you want.

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/so/app/{1,2,3,4}/current/bin
```

Then we can go find them in python.

```py
import glob

bindirs = glob.glob("/tmp/so/app/*/current/bin")
print(bindirs)

>>> ['/tmp/so/app/1/current/bin', '/tmp/so/app/4/current/bin', '/tmp/so/app/3/current/bin', '/tmp/so/app/2/current/bin']
```